# Transform CSV File and Load into PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, csv, etl

My CSV data set has a variable number of columns due to certain groups of fields having a different number of sets based on how I query the data (timeframe).

For example, I have:

```
Field 1 Field 2 Field 3 [Field 4.1.1 Field 4.1.2 Field 4.1.3 Field 4.2.1 Field 4.2.2 Field 4.2.3]
```

My new PostgreSQL tables contain:

```
 - **Table 1**
-------------

 - Field 1 Field 2 Field 3


 - **Table 2**
-------------

 - Field 4.X.1 Field 4.X.2 Field 4.X.3
```

where each X is a new row in table 2.

Recommendations on ETL or other programs to automate this process?

Comment: if the data is  without foreign key constrain that  is easy. If not consider ubdateable view  on the server side. This will give you a good control and performance. Another solution is to use ETL tool such as Pentaho Kettle.

Comment: instead of parsing such csv, refactor csv generation